# Adding 1 second to TimeSpan not working

Tags: c#, timer, win-universal-app

I have this code:

```
 private void TimePlayedTimer_Start()
 {
   timePlayedStr = "00:00:00";
   timePlayed = new DispatcherTimer();
   timePlayed.Tick += timePlayedTimer_Tick;
   timePlayed.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
   timePlayed.Start();
 }

 void timePlayedTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
 {
   TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(timePlayedStr);
   ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
   timePlayedStr = ts.ToString();
 }
```

When I debug this line by line, `TimeSpan ts` would equal `"00:00:00"` but after line `ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` it would some how have properties `TotalDays = 2.313232439423` , `TotalHours = 0.000555555` , `TotalMilliseconds = 2000` rather than adding a `1` to the `TotalSeconds` properties I get these property values returned.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

PS: I am just trying to add a second to the `TimeSpan` after every `tick`

Comment: Can't reproduce, make sure that you notice exponent part in day it should be `1.1574074074074074E-05` , but the millisecond part should be `1000`

Comment: @Habib I've debugged again and I got the same values as you.. Surely I'm adding 1 second so I should just get a `TotalSecond` value of 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value for `TotalDays` is actually `2.31481481481481E-05`, i.e. `0.0000231481481481481`.

The value that you get is exactly what's expected at the second tick, you didn't manage to debug the first tick, and you are just interpreting the values wrong.

The `TotalDays`, `TotalHours` and `TotalMilliseconds` properties show the total value in the `TimeSpan` translated to that specific measurement, they don't form a value together.

2 seconds is the same as 2000 milliseconds, and the same as 0.000555555 hours.

If you want to look at the components in the value, you should look at the `Days`, `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds` and `Milliseconds` properties. There you will find that the `Seconds` property is `2` and all the others are zero.

Comment: But still, I've instantiated a new `TimeSpan` surely `TotalDays` should equal 0?

Comment: @KTOV: The `TotalDays` value is only zero when the `TimeSpan` value is `00:00:00`. When you have added a second then you have added a fraction of a day.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misreading the TotalDays value. When I run similar code I get my `TotalDays` value of `1.15740740740741E-05`. That likely makes sense, one second is probably roughly that fraction of a day.

The `Total*` properties represent the overall value of the `TimeSpan`, not the discrete value of each portion of the `TimeSpan`.

`Days`, `Hours`, and `Minutes` will all be 0, but the `Total*` properties will represent the entirety of the value, even if those parts are fractional.